# Java POI heap out of memory - Batch processing

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to create an excel file using POI. I have around 70000 records. But when I try to write to file, it is resulting in **Heap Out of Memory** exception.

I was wondering if it is possible to write the data in batch. What approach should I use in order to do this?

Comment: what type of excel file you try to create xls or xlsx because xls has a limitation on number of record about 65000  take look at this question : http://superuser.com/questions/366468/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-rows-in-a-microsoft-excel-xls-or-xlsx

Comment: I am writing in .xlsx

Comment: Did you [try reading the Apache POI FAQ topic on memory use](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10165)? Did you [try following the advice there](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10165)?

Answer (score 2):

Apache POI provides a low-memory footprint SXSSF API built on top of XSSF.SXSSF is for Microsoft Excel 2007(xlsx).You can't use it to write xls files.It does exactly what you want and is useful when heap space is limited.It  holds the specified limited number of rows in memory at the time and rows which have already been written to disk become inaccessible.You may want to have a look over [documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)